# Importing values into variable and slap a column name

Tags: powershell

Background: My script currently pulls a list of machines from `MachineName` field from a database. The values are stored in a variable. The variable is an Object with `System.Array` BaseType.
So whenever I read through the `MachineName` from the variable, I would do `$Machines.MachineName`.
Sometimes I want to read through the content from a file or manually add a few values, and store the values in the same variable, $Machines. Using this method, I don't have to change the rest of the codes.

I came up with the code below but it is not ideal. I would like the results to be:

```
MachineName
pc1
pc2
pc3
```

Inside the foreach loop, it will do something like:

```
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $Machines.MachineName
$sourceFile = "C:\machines.txt"
$Machines = get-content -Path $sourceFile
$Machines | select @{label='MachineName';Expression = {$Machines} }
$Machines | Foreach-object { 
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'MachineName' = $Machines
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you hoping somebody will help you rewrite this more elegantly? Are you getting an error? What's the point here?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to **wrap each computer name read from a file in a `[pscustomobject]` instance**:

```bash
$machines = 
  Get-Content C:\machines.txt |
  ForEach-Object { [pscustomobject] @{ MachineName = $_ } }
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

You mistakenly referred to the *whole array* of computer names originally read into `$MachineNames` in your pipelines, instead of referring to *each element (computer name)* via the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_), as shown above.